# How do I escape "Quotes" in a powershell string?

Tags: rest, powershell

I need to send a simple string to a web api using Powershell, and I have to ensure the value in the HTML body has "Quotes" around it, because the content type has to be application/json.

For example:

```
$specialKey = "101010"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put `
                -Uri $keyAssignmentUri `
                -Header @{"content-type"="application/json"} `
                -Body "$specialKey"
```

When I inspect this call in Fiddler, I see that the body is 101010 instead of "101010". How do I send the body value with quotes?

Comment: `-body ($specialKey | ConvertTo-Json)` ?

Comment: Useful [blog on quotation marks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/20/weekend-scripter-understanding-quotation-marks-in-powershell/)

Comment: I wish PowerShell had Python like `r''` or `"""long multiline triple quote """`!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to do variable substitution in your string, a simple solution is to just surround it with single quotes to make it a literal string:

```
$specialKey = '"101010"'
```

Comment: If you have variables in your string such as `$string = 'Found $count records in "test" file'` then this is not a solution as the variable value won't print to the string.  Dipanjan's answer, below, works though.

Comment: I agree this shouldn’t be the accepted answer. It’s a potential solution for some scenarios but it’s not the right answer to the question.

Comment: Seems like powershell 7.3.0 breaks this feature. Use `'\"101010\"'` instead

Answer (score 41):

In order to have the "Quotes", you need to provide the escape character (`) before every " which you want to print or send.

```
$PrintQuotesAsString = "`"How do I escape `"Quotes`" in a powershell string?`"" 

Write-Host $PrintQuotesAsString 

"How do I escape "Quotes" in a powershell string?"
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 10):

Replacing double quotes (") with a sequence of back-slash, backtick and double-quotes worked for me:

```
\`"
```

**Example**: I want to set (using the *env* command) an environment variable named *SCOPES* to the following value, then launch *node app.js*:

```
{
   "email":"Grant permissions to read your email address",
   "address":"Grant permissions to read your address information",
   "phone":"Grant permissions to read your mobile phone number"
}
```

so I used:

```
env SCOPES="{ \`"email\`": \`"Grant permissions to read your email address\`",   \`"address\`": \`"Grant permissions to read your address information\`",   \`"phone\`": \`"Grant permissions to read your mobile phone number\`" }" node app.js
```

References: http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm